# Create and user loadUserByEmail instead of loadUserByUsername

Tags: java, spring, security

I m looking a way to create and use my own method to load user in Java Spring Security.

I would like to retrieve my user not by UserName but by email.

```
public class UserDetailsService implements org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
UserRepository userRepository;

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserDetailsService.class);

public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    Optional<User> oUser = userRepository.findByUserName(userName);

    if(!oUser.isPresent()){
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(userName);
    } else {
        logger.info("user found");
    }

    User user = oUser.get();
    return this.buildUserDetails(user);
}
```

But loadUserByUsername is called in this method in class DaoAuthenticationProvider. How can i override this behavior ?

```
protected final UserDetails retrieveUser(String username, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
    UserDetails loadedUser;
    try {
        loadedUser = this.getUserDetailsService().loadUserByUsername(username);
    } catch (UsernameNotFoundException var6) {
        if (authentication.getCredentials() != null) {
            String presentedPassword = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
            this.passwordEncoder.isPasswordValid(this.userNotFoundEncodedPassword, presentedPassword, (Object)null);
        }

        throw var6;
    } catch (Exception var7) {
        throw new InternalAuthenticationServiceException(var7.getMessage(), var7);
    }

    if (loadedUser == null) {
        throw new InternalAuthenticationServiceException("UserDetailsService returned null, which is an interface contract violation");
    } else {
        return loadedUser;
    }
}
```

## Solution

My WebSecurityConfig here with customDaoAuthenticationProvider

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceExtended userDetailsServiceExtended;
    @Autowired
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint customAuthenticationEntryPoint;
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler;
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler;
    @Autowired
    protected TokenAuthenticationService tokenAuthenticationService;

    @Value("${web.security.debug}")
    private boolean debug;

    public WebSecurityConfig() { super(false);}

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .cors()
            .and()
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated();
        http
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(customAuthenticationEntryPoint);

        http
            .addFilterBefore(customEmailPasswordAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .addFilterBefore(new StatelessAuthenticationFilter(tokenAuthenticationService), CustomEmailPasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomEmailPasswordAuthenticationFilter customEmailPasswordAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
        CustomEmailPasswordAuthenticationFilter filter = new CustomEmailPasswordAuthenticationFilter();
        filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler);
        filter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler);
        filter.setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/users/authenticate", "POST"));
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        return filter;
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomDaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
        CustomDaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new CustomDaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(this.passwordEncoder);
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsServiceExtended);
        return authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());
        auth.userDetailsService(this.userDetailsServiceExtended).passwordEncoder(this.passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManager();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have both a username and an email? or is the email used as username?

Comment: the email is the "username"

Comment: Then it's fine, you don't have to change anything. `loadUserByUsername` comes from `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService` and is automatically called by Spring Security, you can't rename it to `loadUserByEmail`.

Comment: I know i can't rename it, but i m looking a way to override this behavior, to create my own way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your direct question, `retrieveUser` cannot be overriden. Not only is it `final`, indicating that it cannot be overriden, it's protected, meaning that you can't access it from outside the `org.springframework.security.authentication.dao` package.

Obviously, I wouldn't be answering without a solution.

Spring's biggest forte is its layer of abstraction. A lot of people misunderstand its use, but in simple terms, as long as a class extends the same abstract class as the default class, it can be replaced by using the `@Bean` annotation.

So in your case, `DaoAuthenticationProvider` extends `AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider`. Following that logic, as long as we make a class that extends `AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider` and configure it accordingly, we should be able to replace `DaoAuthenticationProvider`.

Let's call that class `CustomDaoAuthenticationProvider`.

```
public class CustomDaoAuthenticationProvider extends AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider {

}
```

Copy everything from DaoAuthenticationProvider [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/authentication/dao/DaoAuthenticationProvider.java).

**The only difference is that the constructor and the class name should be renamed from `DaoAuthenticationProvider` to `CustomDaoAuthenticationProvider`.**

If you're using a different version of Spring, you should be able to just navigate to the source code of `DaoAuthenticationProvider` from your IDE.

Now you'll need to create a configuration class, let's call it `SecurityConfiguration`:

```
@Configuration
@WebSecurity // optional?
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired 
    private UserDetailsService userService; // can be replaced by whatever service implements UserDetailsService

    @Bean
    public CustomDaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
        CustomDaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new CustomDaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userService);
        System.out.println("Using my custom DaoAuthenticationProvider");
        return authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }


    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    // ...

}
```

The following configuration should tell Spring to use `CustomDaoAuthenticationProvider` instead of `DaoAuthenticationProvider`.

I briefly tested it on my end, and it should work. From there, you can modify `retrieveUser` directly in `CustomDaoAuthenticationProvider` as you wish.

Good luck!

Comment: @mik3fly-4steri5k Updated my answer. You also needed to set the authentication provider by `configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder)`