# Multi basic auth with spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I want to use basic auth, but i need use in `UserDetailsService` not only username but also some info from header(header contains type of user). 
This is bacause I have 2 users with same names but with varios types. For example, I have `name:user1 type:USER psw: 1` and `name:user1 type:PLAYER psw:1`. So when I login as first user, i should search in db user with `name=user1` and `type=USER`, but `UserDetailsService` has only this method `loadUserByUsername(String login)`. 
So how can i do this?

My `UserDetailsService`:

```
public class UserDetailsService implements org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService {

    private final UserService userService;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String login) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return userService.findUserDetailsByLogin(login).orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException(login));
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know if the client wants to log in as USER or PLAYER?

Comment: Can you add your `UserDetailsService`?

Comment: @aBnormaLz front send me header `X-Type`

Comment: @YoManTaMero how, if `BasicAuthenticationFilter` use method from `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService`?

Comment: `UserService` is not spring class right and it is yours?

Comment: Well this looks like a badly designed login flow

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50099192/create-and-user-loaduserbyemail-instead-of-loaduserbyusername - this post has example of overridding `retrieveUser` method of `DaoAuthenticationProvider.java`, that actually calls `loadUserByUsername()`. Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to use a static context. Using `CustomFilter`, I create a context and then use it in the `loadUserByUsername` method

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TypeFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
   private final TypeService typeService;
   private final ObjectMapper mapper;

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String uri = request.getRequestURI();
    if (!uri.contains("/login") && !uri.contains("/password")) {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        return;
    }

    String headerValue = request.getHeader(TYPE);

    if (StringUtils.isBlank(headerValue)) {
       response.setStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value());
        return;
    }

    try {
        Type type = type Service.findByValue(headerValue);
        TypeContext.setCurrentType(type);
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    } catch (MyException e) {
       response.setStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value());
    }
}
```

}

My config:

```
 @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .addFilterBefore(typeFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
```

And then I use context in `UserDeatilsService`:

```
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String login) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    Type type = TypeContext.getCurrentType();
    return userService.findUser(login, type).orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException(login));
}
```

Comment: Is that because you don't want UserDetailsService to know about `HttpServletRequest` or you will be reusing `TypeContext` other places?

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai  both: i need Type in other places and i don't want that `UserDetailsService` know about `HttpServletRequest `

Answer (score -1):

You could warp the `loadUserByUsername(String login)` method into an other method. And extract with `@RequestHeader("YourHeader")` the additional Information you want.